# Public programmatic access to catalogs of foreign shops

Tags: api, products

I'm developing a solution that would benefit from access to public product catalog information of Magento shops in cases where my customers have those.

The APIs give me that information, public and private depending on permissions, but it would be a much greater benefit, especially for sales, if I wouldn't have to register my application with every shop to make that happen (I believe that's necessary with the apis, even for public information).

Crawling the shops' public web pages seems too complex as the markup is too different between the shops.

Is there another way, perhaps Magento exposes this information in yet another I don't yet know about?

I only need the general structure and the product names and images.

Comment: There's a reason that there is no unauthorized access to APIs.

Comment: @benmarks Presumably because they are normally used to do a bit more than merely read public data.

Answer (score 2):

Four options apply (I've changed my answer from only sitemap to four options)

- You can use a generated **sitemap.xml** for each shop?
  There are default priorities for each, so makes guessing easy which are products.
  Of coarse you don't know yet in which categories products are.

  ```
  <page>
      <priority>0.25</priority>
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  </page>
  <category>
      <priority>0.5</priority>
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  </category>
  <product>
      <priority>1</priority>
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  </product>
  ```
- Or build a **custom module** which you can send to your customers which can communicate with your API (so the other way around)
- Or just go with the **API**(which indeed needs a valid user which @benmarks correctly points out)
- Or build **crawlers** for each site.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: It was my first vision on this question... because in my opinion this is eventually the basic data which is provided out of the box in Magento

Comment: The sitemap doesn't contain the information which of the links are products (as opposed to category pages, for example), and it doesn't reflect organizational structure (such as categories, tags, etc.) the products are organized in. It is still useful, of course.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the four options you have